# How do I create a string consisting of characters read from a text file?

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm trying to read code and format it so that it cuts off and goes to a new line after a certain point. At first I tried to simply keep displaying the successive characters and making it go into a newline after the amount of characters read at that point had surpassed the limit. However, if a word *will* go over the limit, I'm required to have that word start the new line. As I have absolutely no clue how to do that with just characters, I decided to try using an array of strings. My code is as follows

```
char ch;
string words[999];
//I use 999 because I can not be sure how large the text file will be, but I doubt it   would be over 999 words
string wordscount[999];
//again, 999. wordscount will store how many characters are in the word
int wordnum = 0;
int currentnum = 0;
//this will be used later
while (documentIn.get(ch))
{
if (ch != ' ')
//this makes sure that the character being read isn't a space, as spaces are how we differentiate words from each other
{
cout << ch;
//this displays the character being read
```

At about here in my code, I would like to 'save' all characters to a string, until the character is a space. I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me out here? I figured it would be something like this;

```
words[wordnum] = 'however i add up the characters'
//assuming I would use a type of loop to keep adding characters until I reach a 
//space, I would also be using the ++currentnum command to keep track of how
//many characters are in the word
wordscount[wordnum] = currentnum;
++wordnum;
```

Comment: Realize the iostream extraction operator skips whitespace when pulling a `std::string`, but uses it for delimiting, and this can be done in literally few lines of code.

Comment: I honestly had no idea what that meant, but I looked up the delimiter and I think I understand now? I know that I can declare the space delimiter as `std::string delimiter = " ";` but, I don't know the syntax of how to make it do that for the entire program. I'd like to do some kind of loop, kind of like the following;

'syntax to split up the first word';
'first word' = words[wordnum];
'count the amount of chars in the word' = wordscount[wordnum];
wordnum++;

Am I going about it the right way? How do I do the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Use an input file stream to loop over the words adding them to a vector, then vector.size() will be the word count.

```
std::ifstream ifs("myfile.txt");

std::vector<std::string> words;
std::string word;
while (ifs >> word)
   words.push_back(word);
```

White space will be skipped by default and the while loop will continue until the end of the file is reached.

Comment: The following code wouldn't work though. The file is not opened through something like "myfile.txt", it's given through a command line parameter. The code `char ch; while (documentIn.get(ch)) {}` was valid, but I can't just replace ifs with documentIn. I'm not entirely sure how the streams work.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you really want to do.

If you want to restore each line from the file, you can do it like this:

```
std::ifstream ifs("in");
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::string word;
while (std::getline(ifs, word))
{
    words.push_back(word);
}
ifs.close();
```

Function std::getline() will NOT OMIT white space, such as ‘ ’, '\t' , while that will be descasted via ifs >> word.